# Redis Error while writing bytes to the server. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I just started using redis to cache data and run queries. I have two functions, one for fetching the data, and another one for filtering the cached data. This is how my function for fetching data looks :

```
if (Auth::user()->access_level == 'Admin' || Auth::user()->access_level == 'Donor') {
    $clients_number = Cache::remember('all_clients_number', 21600, function () {
       return ClientPerformance::whereNotNull('actual_clients')->get();
    });

    $all_clients_number = Cache::remember('all_clients_sum', 21600, function () use ($clients_number) {
      return $clients_number->sum('actual_clients');
   });

} else if(Auth::user()->access_level == 'Partner') {
       $clients_number = Cache::remember('all_partner_clients_number', 21600, function () {
          return ClientPerformance::whereNotNull('actual_clients')
            ->where('partner_id', Auth::user()->partner_id)
            ->get();
       });

     $all_clients_number = Cache::remember('all_partner_clients_sum', 21600, function () use ($clients_number) {
      return $clients_number->sum('actual_clients');
     });
}
```

I have confirmed that my redis service is running and i changed the maximum memory limit in my php.ini file to be 4096.

This is how my function to filter the data looks like :

```
   $selected_counties = $request->counties;

   if (Auth::user()->access_level == 'Admin' || Auth::user()->access_level == 'Donor') {

            $all_clients_number = Cache::remember('all_clients_number', 21600, function () {
                return ClientPerformance::whereNotNull('actual_clients');
            });
   } else if(Auth::user()->access_level == 'Partner') {
          $all_clients_number = Cache::remember('all_partner_clients_number', 21600, function () {
                return ClientPerformance::whereNotNull('actual_clients');
          });
   }

   if (!empty($selected_counties)) {
            $all_clients_number = $all_clients_number->where('county_id', $selected_counties);
   }

   $data["all_clients_number"]        = $all_clients_number->sum('actual_clients');
```

Is it good practice to access the cached data from another function like this  `Cache::remember(key)` and what could be the reason why i cant write anything to redis despite the fact that the data im caching is not that heavy.

Any advise or links to places i can read how to effectively access cached redit data will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: @cottton the error when i load the page is ```Error while writing bytes to the server. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]
```

Comment: What code is in `Cache::remember()`. As i can see you send an anon function into it as data.

Comment: You seem like to execute the callable, cache it, and return the data. Only you can test WHAT data has been tried to cache when this error happen.

Comment: @shiro what is your redis version?

Comment: @shiro from redis-cli can you provide this memory info : `INFO memory` ?

Comment: @shiro what is your driver? phpredis or predis?

Comment: @Abilogos Redis server v=3.0.504 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=a4f7a6e86f2d60b3

Comment: i am using predis

Comment: and what about this : INFO memory ?

Comment: and this : `CONFIG GET maxmemory`

Answer (score 0):

There are some workaround which can solve the issue this:

- update the redis server to version 5 or 6
- `CONFIG SET maxmemory 0`

Comment: Unfortunately, the error still persists even when i try                                                         ```   ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
````